# What will be safest and least stressful for my cats?

Tags: cats, safety, psychology

So we plan to go away for 7 days. So which of the following is the best for my Cats?

1. Leave them at home and have someone reliable feed them.
2. Put them in Cat hotel for the 7 days.

The pro for number 1 is that they stay in their environment so I think this maybe less stressful, but the con is that this may not be the safest. The pro for number 2 is that they will be safe, but I assume that it will be stressful for the cats as they have never been out of their home environment (other than trips to the Vet) and are wary of strangers. They hide away whenever we have strangers in the house. Both cats are chipped, spayed and are two and a half years old.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaving for vacation, leave cat alone or move it to other house?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17241/leaving-for-vacation-leave-cat-alone-or-move-it-to-other-house)

Comment: @ Allison C This question has also assisted me in making my decision.

Comment: How easy is for you to find someone reliable, both for the cats and for your home? Nr.2 here seems to be a big no. I suppose you already dismissed the nr.3, buying an automatic cat feeder (really bad choice).

Comment: @ Quora Feans The Cat Sitter stays on the property and is in and out our house at least once a week so the cats are familiar with her.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would *assume* that your home is reasonably cat safe - because of course as a responsible cat owner you will already have made sure of that (e.g. removed poisonous plants). And of course you can always do a quick check before you leave and remove or secure typical traps like shopping bags with handles or boxes with lids that can be pushed open and fall closed. Or restrict access to some rooms entirely, if necessary. Same goes for instructions to the sitter, like to ensure doors (both room and furniture) and windows are closed properly.

Under that premise, having someone come to your home to feed your cats, clean the litter box etc. would in my opinion be a much better choice than a cat hotel.
I have myself been cat sitting a few times, including very shy cats. An experienced sitter will notice if something is amiss on a large scale, e.g. if the cats refused to eat. The he cats being wary of strangers isn’t necessarily a problem - a sitter waiting quietly in some unobtrusive spot may still be able to at least *see* them, on their way to the food bowl or so, and thus ascertain that everything is well, or well enough considering the circumstances.

The stress caused by your absence and a stranger coming to your home is less than being dragged from their home and being “abandoned” in a completely strange place. Note that your cats have no idea of what’s suddenly going on and no concept of “temporary holidays” - they are suddenly somewhere strange and scary, and without you. And if they are not used to strangers (as you write), the personnel at the cat hotel won’t be able to console them or play/cuddle with them.

If you have a bit of a head start before leaving, you could also try to introduce the sitter to your cats well beforehand - simply by them being around every now and then and possibly feeding them while you are still present. But in a pinch, I would get a sitter and leave.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. Our sitter lives on the property and the Cats are used to her.

Comment: @Anthony I agree with this advice from recent pet sitter experiences from my recent absences of 3, 3, and 10 days. However I found my cat remained perturbed and committed offenses against my couch 1 or 2 days after I returned, completely clean litter boxes available. This happened twice. No medical issues at vet. So after you return, plan on re-connecting to your cat and reassuring them.